# CONCATENATE function with dynamic range

Tags: excel, range

I'd like to have a `CONCATENATE` function with a dynamic range. The range can be very different, see example below. Would it be possible to do this by a simple code?

[image: example]

The range is intended for rows only, where the number of non-empty cells in column is different. I need to pair every two cells as well, like in example.

Comment: It would help to see what other ranges you would need too? Would the next one be C18,D18,E18,F18? etc for each row?

Comment: @99moorem No. The range is intended for rows only, where the number of non-empty cells is different. I need to pair every two cells as well, like in example.

Answer (score 0):

try this - you may need to change C1 to the start of your data

```
Sub test()
i = 0
i2 = 0
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In .Range("C1:" & .Range("C1").End(xlDown).Address)
        i2 = 0
        temp = ""
        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(cell.Row, 3), .Cells(cell.Row, 3).End(xlToRight).Address)
            If i = 0 Then
                i = 1
            Else 'every other column
                If i2 = 0 Then'first for each row needs no extra comma
                    i = 0
                    temp = "(" & .Cells(cell.Row, -1 + c.Column).Value & "," & .Cells(cell.Row, 1 + c.Column).Value & ")"
                Else
                    i = 0
                    temp = temp & ",(" & .Cells(cell.Row, -1 + c.Column).Value & "," & .Cells(cell.Row, c.Column).Value & ")"
                End If
                i2 = i2 + 1
            End If
        Next
        .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = temp 'put string into column A
    Next
End With
End Sub
```